# How to handle lots of small tensorflow models for server predictions on a GPU

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am planning on creating lots of fairly small (I imagine ~50MB) classification models for each user of my application. I have two main models that are ~500MB each lets call them `A` and `B`.

I have a python script that first loads the models `A` and `B` and then creates a local socket which listens for a string with a path to an image file (sent when a user uploads an image over HTTP) where it then runs `predict` for model `A` and then `B` with the input image.

This is a great and efficient but I now need to add my small model custom to the user who uploaded the image but this will likely immensely slow down the system as the system will need to load this model each time a request is made (takes far longer than the predict method). Is there anyway around this?

My 6GB 1060 GPU is limited to `~100` small models:

```
((6000 - 1000)/50) = ((6GB - (A + B))/small model)`
```

so I cannot attempt to just load all the models individually as I would like to potentially have more than 100 users.

I am likely going to create a model python script session for each of these users with the same idea as the first python script and the first python script will send a socket message with the output of model `B` to the small model session.

These small models are also going to be trained individually (periodically) for privacy and efficiency reasons so I can't just create one large model `C` (I don't think).

I hope my problem makes sense. Please ask questions!